# Validating all attributes except one in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

I'm trying to do a custom validation in my model using `valid?` method. I need to run all validations of this model, except the password.

Something like this:

```
@resource = SalesPartner.new(permitted_params.merge(parent: current_sales_partner))

respond_to do |format|

  if @resource.valid?(except: :password)
    @resource.generate_authentication_token

    SalesPartnerMailer.mail_new_sales_partner(@resource.email,
      { auth_token: @resource.authentication_token, id: @resource.id, level: @resource.level }
    ).deliver

    flash[:success] = "#{@resource.level} criado com sucesso."
    format.html { render "#{@path}/index" }
  else
    logger.log_and_alert_save_error(@resource, flash, "Ocorreu um erro ao salvar.")
    format.html { render "#{@path}/new" }
  end

end
```

Is that possible?

Thanks everyone!

Comment: What is the validation you are trying to run.

Comment: `valid?` will run the validations that you have registered with the corresponding model(`resource` class).

Comment: Updated code. I need to skip the password validation, so the SalesPartner object will be created without a password in this case. Note: SalesPartner is using Devise which has a validation for password.

Comment: You didn't get me. what is the stuff you are validating ?

Comment: I'm validating presence of name, email, and have a custom validation for coupon_discount attribute.

Comment: THANK you very much for asking this question. Just for YOU I learned something new today.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Any way here is a way that you can do with the help of *context*. Say you have a `User` model and you want to validates some fields.

```
validates_presence_of :name,: email, on: :special_context
validates_presence_of :name,:email, :password
```

With the above 2 lines, you can now do like below

```
@user.valid?(:special_context)
```

The above will validates `name` and `email` fields. And if you write now,

```
@user.valid?
```

This will perform the presence validations on the `name`, `email` and `password` fields as you wrote.

Read [`valid?(context = nil)`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Validations.html#method-i-validate) to understand the *context*.

> Runs all the validations within the specified context. If the argument is `false` (default is `nil`), the context is set to `:create` if `new_record?` is true, and to `:update` if it is not.
>
> Validations with no `:on` option will run no matter the context. Validations with some `:on` option will only run in ***the specified context***.

Check this [documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Validations.html#method-i-valid-3F) also as an official example.

Comment: Wow, helped me a lot! Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Context could really help you, but following maybe not.

```
validates_presence_of :name,: email, on: :special_context
validates_presence_of :name,:email, :password
```

This is because when you use validates_presence_of without specifying its context, it will be applied to **all context(nil)**. Please see ref [here](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods/validates_presence_of) So, maybe you could try as follow code:

```
validates_presence_of :name, :email, on: :special_context
validates_presence_of :name, :email, :password, on: [ :create, :update]
```

Answer (score 2):

Just found one more mechanism to skip some validation on specified context, because specify all other context is not always suitable:

```rb
validates_presence_of :name, :email, on: :special_context
validates_presence_of :name, :email, :password, if: -> {Array(validation_context).exclude?(:special_context)}
```

note: `validation_context` can be array.